# Using a Livedata observer in a worker

Tags: java, android, mvvm, android-service

I have a Worker service to send some simple notification. But now, I want to check some data from database before sending it.

But, I can't use an observer in a Worker Thread, it must be in the Main thread. I have an error type `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot invoke observeForever on a background thread`

What's the best solution to access my Room Database data ?

```
public class NotificationWorker extends Worker {

    FavoriteRepository favoriteRepository;

    public NotificationWorker(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams) {
        super(context, workerParams);
        favoriteRepository = new FavoriteRepository(((MainApplication) context.getApplicationContext()));
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Result doWork() {

        favoriteRepository.getAllFavorites().observeForever(new Observer<List<Favorite>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<Favorite> favorites) {
                // get data
            }
        });
        showNotification("WorkManager", "Content of message");
        return Result.success();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some research, i could find how i can  perform work asynchronously in WorkManager by using [ListenableWorker](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/ListenableWorker)